# Exercises to enforce good practices such as TDD and Mocking

Tags: tdd, mocking

I'm looking for **resources** that provide an **actual lesson plan or path** to encourage and reinforce programming practices such as **TDD** and **mocking**.  There are plenty of resources that show examples, but I'm looking for something that actually provides a **progression** that allows the concepts to be learned **instead of forcing emulation**.

My primary goal is speeding up the process for someone to understand the concepts behind TDD and actually be effective at implementing them.  Are there any free resources like this?

Comment: Your question might be better phrased as "encourage" or "educate" rather than "enforce".

Comment: Enforcing these is an anti-pattern, likely to backfire.

Comment: @Nat: Good call, post edited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a difficult thing to encourage because it can be perceived (quite fairly) as a sea-change; not so much a progression to a goal but an entirely different approach to things.

The short-list of advice is:

- You need to be the leader, you need to become proficient before you can convince others to, you need to be able to show others the path and settle their uncertainties.
- First become proficient in writing unit tests yourself

  - Practice writing tests for existing methods.  You'll probably beat your head on the desk trying to test lots of your code--it's not because testing is hard or you can't understand testing; it's more likely because your existing code and coding style isn't very testable.
  - If you have a hard time getting started then find the simplest methods you can and use them as a starting point.
- Then focus on improving the testability of the code you produce

  - The single biggest tip: make things smaller and more to the point.  This one is the big change--this is the hardest part to get yourself to do, and even harder to convince others of.

Personally I had my "moment of clarity" while reading Bob Martin's "Clean Code" book; an early chapter talks about what a clean method will look like and as an example he takes a ~40 line method that visually resembled something I'd produce and refactors it out into a class which is barely larger line-count wise but consists of nothing but bite-sized methods that are perhaps 3-7 lines each.

Looking at these itty-bitty methods it suddenly clicked that the unit-testing cornerstone "each test only tests one thing" is easiest to achieve when your methods only do one thing (and do that one thing without having 30 internal mechanisms at play).

The good thing is that you can begin to apply your findings immediately; practice writing small methods and small classes and testing along the way.  You'll probably start out slow, and hit a few snags fairly quickly, but the first couple months will help get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

You could try attending (or hosting one if there is none near you!) a [coding dojo](http://codingdojo.org/.)

I attended one such excercise and it was fun learning TDD.

Answer (score 3):

Books are always a good resource - even though not free - they may be worth your time searching for the good free resources - for the money those books cost.

["Test driven development by example"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) by Kent Beck.

["Test Driven Development in Microsoft .NET"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619484) by James W. Newkirk and Alexei A. Vorontsov

**please feel free to add to this list**

Comment: To add to the "heard it's good, but haven't read it"; "Test Driven Development in Microsfot .NET" is supposed to be solid--if you're working with .NET of course

Answer (score 2):

One thing I worked through that helped me appreciate TDD more was [NHibernate and the Unit of Work Pattern](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx). Although it's specific to NHibernate and .NET, I liked the way that it was arranged. Using TDD, you develop something (a UnitofWork) that's actually useful rather than some simple "this is what a mock looks like" example.

How I learn a concept best is by putting it to use towards an actual need. I suggest you take a look at the structure of the article and see if it's along the lines of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Geeks are excellent at working to metrics, whether they are good for them or not!

You can use this to your advantage. Set up a CI server and fail the build whenever code coverages drops below 50 percent. Let them know that the threshold will rise 10 percent every month until it's 90. You could perhaps use some commit hooks to stop them being able to check code in to begin with but I've never tried this myself.

Let them know the coverage by the *team* will be taken into effect in any performance reviews, etc. By emphasising it is the coverage of the team, you should get peer pressure helping you ensure good coverage.

This will only ensure they are testing their code, not how well they are testing their code, nor whether they are writing the tests first. However, it is strongly encouraging (or forcing) them to incorporate testing into their daily development process.

Generally, once people have something in their process they'll want to do something as easily/ efficiently as possible. TDD is the easiest way to write code with high coverage as you don't write a line of code without it being covered.

Answer (score 1):

Find someone with experience and talk to them. If there isn't a local developer group, then start one.

You should also try pushing things too far to start with, and then learn when to back off. For example, the whole mock thing started when someone asked "What if we program with no getters".

Finally, learn to "listen to the tests". When the tests look dreadful, consider whether it's the code that's at fault, not your testing technique.